# Nested for loop keeps repeating

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a python scraper main purpose

Read list of postcodes from text to an array

for each postcode in array
search 10 pages
pull out certain content.

i seem to be getting the results like:
page 1
page 2
page 2
page 3
page 3
page 3
page 4
page 4
page 4 
page 4

etc

i have tried re arranging the code several times without much look, everything works fine expcept this step

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import csv

print(" Initializing ...")
print(" Loading Keywords")
with open("pcodes.txt") as pcodes:
    postkeys = []
    for line in pcodes:
        postkeys.append(line.strip())

with open("pcodnum.txt") as pcodnum:
    postkeynum = []
    for line in pcodnum:
        postkeynum.append(line.strip())

print(" Welcome to YellScrape v1.0")
print(" You ar searching yell.com ")

comtype = input(" Please enter a Company Type (e.g Newsagent, Barber): ")
pagesnum = 0
listinnum = 0
comloc = " "
f = csv.writer(open(datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '-' + comtype + '-' + 'yelldata.csv', 'w'))
f.writerow(['Business Name', 'Business Type', 'Phone Number', 'Street Address', 'Locality', 'Region', 'Website'])

headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
    }

data_list = []
for x in postkeys:
    print(" Searching " + x + " for " + comtype + " companies")
    for y in postkeynum:
        url = 'https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?keywords=' + comtype + '&pageNum=' + str(y) + '&location=' + x
        data_list.append(url)
        for item in data_list:
            site = requests.get(item, headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(site.content, 'html.parser')
            questions = soup.select('.businessCapsule--mainContent')
            for question in questions:
                listinnum += 1
                busname = question.find(class_='businessCapsule--name').get_text()
                bustype =   question.find(class_='businessCapsule--classification').get_text()
                busnumber = question.select_one('span.business--telephoneNumber')
                if busnumber is None:
                    busnumber = 'None'
                else:
                    busnumber = busnumber.text
                busadd = question.find('span', attrs={"itemprop": "streetAddress"})
                if busadd is None:
                    busadd = 'None'
                else:
                    busadd = busadd.text.replace(',',' ')
                buslocal = question.find('span', attrs={"itemprop": "addressLocality"})
                if buslocal is None:
                    buslocal = 'None'
                else:
                    buslocal = buslocal.text
                buspost = question.find('span', attrs={"itemprop": "postalCode"})
                if buspost is None:
                    buspost = 'None'
                else:
                    buspost = buspost.text
                busweb = question.find('a', attrs={"rel": "nofollow noopener"})
                if busweb is None:
                    busweb = 'None'
                else:
                    busweb = busweb.attrs['href']
                print(busweb)
                f.writerow([busname, bustype, busnumber, busadd, buslocal, buspost, busweb])


        pagesnum += 1
        print(" Finsihed Page " + str(y) + ". For " + x + " . " + str(listinnum) + " listings so far. Moving To Next Page")
    print(" Waiting 30 seconds for security reasons.")
    sleep(30)
print(" Finished. \n Total: " + str(pagesnum) + " pages with " + str(listinnum) + " listings. \n Please look for file: " + datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '-' + comtype + '-' + 'yelldata.csv')
```

Expected result:

finished page 1
finished page 2
finished page 3

etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are appending to your data list and then using a for loop to iterate through it after each time it's appending a new link.

So it's going to do `requests` for page 1, then `requests` for page 1 and `requests` for page 2, then page 1, 2 and 3, then page 1, 2, 3, and 4... etc.

So there's 2 ways to fix that. 1) don't append to the data_list and eliminate that all together, or 2) you can append to the data_list FIRST, and then loop through it (so separate the loop where you append to `data_list` and iterate through `data_list`.

I choose option 2)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import csv

print(" Initializing ...")
print(" Loading Keywords")
with open("C:/pcodes.txt") as pcodes:
    postkeys = []
    for line in pcodes:
        postkeys.append(line.strip())

with open("C:/pcodnum.txt") as pcodnum:
    postkeynum = []
    for line in pcodnum:
        postkeynum.append(line.strip())

print(" Welcome to YellScrape v1.0")
print(" You are searching yell.com ")

comtype = input(" Please enter a Company Type (e.g Newsagent, Barber): ")
pagesnum = 0
listinnum = 0
comloc = " "
f = csv.writer(open('C:/'+datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '-' + comtype + '-' + 'yelldata.csv', 'w'))
f.writerow(['Business Name', 'Business Type', 'Phone Number', 'Street Address', 'Locality', 'Region', 'Website'])

headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
    }

data_list = []
for x in postkeys:
    print(" Searching " + x + " for " + comtype + " companies")
    for y in postkeynum:
        url = 'https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?keywords=' + comtype + '&pageNum=' + str(y) + '&location=' + x
        data_list.append(url)

    # Now that you created a list of the urls, now you can loop through them


    for item in data_list:

        page = item.split('pageNum=')[-1].split('&')[0]
        location = item[-5:]

        site = requests.get(item, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(site.content, 'html.parser')
        questions = soup.select('.businessCapsule--mainContent')
        for question in questions:
            listinnum += 1
            busname = question.find(class_='businessCapsule--name').get_text()
            bustype =   question.find(class_='businessCapsule--classification').get_text()
            busnumber = question.select_one('span.business--telephoneNumber')
            if busnumber is None:
                busnumber = 'None'
            else:
                busnumber = busnumber.text
            busadd = question.find('span', attrs={"itemprop": "streetAddress"})
            if busadd is None:
                busadd = 'None'
            else:
                busadd = busadd.text.replace(',',' ')
            buslocal = question.find('span', attrs={"itemprop": "addressLocality"})
            if buslocal is None:
                buslocal = 'None'
            else:
                buslocal = buslocal.text
            buspost = question.find('span', attrs={"itemprop": "postalCode"})
            if buspost is None:
                buspost = 'None'
            else:
                buspost = buspost.text
            busweb = question.find('a', attrs={"rel": "nofollow noopener"})
            if busweb is None:
                busweb = 'None'
            else:
                busweb = busweb.attrs['href']
            print(busweb)
            f.writerow([busname, bustype, busnumber, busadd, buslocal, buspost, busweb])


        pagesnum += 1
        print(" Finished Page " + page + ". For " + location + " . " + str(listinnum) + " listings so far. Moving To Next Page")


    if item != data_list[-1]:
        print(" Waiting 30 seconds for security reasons.")
        sleep(30)
print(" Finished. \n Total: " + str(pagesnum) + " pages with " + str(listinnum) + " listings. \n Please look for file: " + datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '-' + comtype + '-' + 'yelldata.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize pageNum inside for loop:

```
for x in postkeys:
   pageNum = 1
```

Increment pageNum side for loop and format URL

```
for item in data_list:
    #format website url
    url = "https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?keywords={}&pageNum={}&location={}".format(comtype, pageNum, x)
    site = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    # check response status code:
    if site.status_code != 200:
        break

    pageNum += 1
```

You should remove this for loop:

```
for y in postkeynum:
        url = 'https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?keywords=' + comtype + '&pageNum=' + str(y) + '&location=' + x
        data_list.append(url)
```